# angularjs ng-show not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I want to show and hide a button with ng-show directive.

Here is my ***HTML file***:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-show="editBtn">Save Edit
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </button>
```

Here is my ***controllerScript file***:

```
    myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller ("epmloyeeCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.editBtn = false;
}]);
```

Comment: What happen with this code?

Comment: the button will be shown ,or i think with this code the button should be hide

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? We don't have enough to debug. Can you create a copy of your code on plunker? What if you change the ng-show with an ng-if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your forgot `ng-app` or `ng-controller` in HTML. It should be:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="epmloyeeCtrl">
     <button class="btn btn-info" ng-show="editBtn">Save Edit
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller ("epmloyeeCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  $scope.editBtn = false;
}]);
```

I have demo about `Show/Hide Edit Button` from your code: [Here!](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/RRPEVL)

Answer (score 1):

Check this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/veAeGPtYQIq9IQlBc1Ob?p=preview

It looks like you forgot to change the state of $scope.editBtn when click edit button. In the controller, function editEmployee, you must add:

```
$scope.editBtn=true;
```

Plus, I add the variable saveBtn to hide while the user is editing. And added a cancel button too. You can check this 3 elements in the plnkr.